# JavaScript form validator

Tags: javascript, validation

I want to create a validator for password field. Here are my requirements:

- minimum length 5 characters, maximum length 20 characters.
- allow alpha, numeric, and special characters.
- do not have space.

I use js form validator to write it. Here is the code that I write:

```
frmvalidator.addValidation("password","regexp=/^[a-z0-9A-Z!#$@]{5,20}\S+$/", "Invalid password format.");
```

My problem is the space does not excluded from password field. What am I did wrong? How should I modify so that can fulfill my above requirements?

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9#$@!\\]{5,20}$/` should be enough. This already ensures, you only have alpha numberic + special characters with the length restrict in the full password from start (^) to end ($).

Answer (score 1):

```
regexp=/^[a-z0-9A-Z!#$@\\]{5,20}+$/"
```

just include  like this

```
your expression was wrong...
```

Another  example regular expression

```
^[\d\w#$@!\\]{5,20}$
```